# Having trouble with showing a basic property of the gradient of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, vector-analysis, gradient-descent

Consider functions of the type

$$f(ax) = a^k f(x)$$

where $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$

A simple example is $f(x) = x^k$.

Then I claim,

> $$\nabla f(ax)^T(a \delta_i) = a^k \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}
>  (x)$$

where $\delta_i$ is the vector of all zeroes except for $1$ at the ith position.

Cannot show this. I always have a $a^{k+1}$ on the right hand side. I suspect there might be a typo? Can someone please verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no typo. For your example you get $\nabla f(x) = k x^{k-1}$, so $\nabla f(ax)a = k(ax)^{k-1}a = a^{k}(kx^{k-1}) = a^k \nabla f(x)$

You apparently made the mistake to go from $$f(ax) = a^k f(x)$$ to$$\nabla f(ax) = a^k \nabla f(x).$$
That is not true, because you think that you take  the derivative with respect to $x$ whereas you actually take the derivative w.r.t. $ax$ on the left hand side. To compute $\frac{d}{dx} f(ax)$ you need the chain rule:
$f(ax) = f(h(x))$ with $h(x) = ax$, so $\frac{df(ax)}{dx} = \frac{df(h(x))}{dh}\frac{dh}{dx} = \nabla f \cdot a$.

Comment: Hi. I think  I made the mistake $\nabla f(ax) = \nabla a^k f(x) = a^k \nabla f(x)$. Then multiply both sides with $a$, you get $a^{k+1} \nabla f(x)$. Can you spot my mistake? The second step I used the property $f(ax ) = a^k f(x)$.

Comment: yes, you have to use the chain rule instead, I will update my answer

Comment: Is the following valid, $\dfrac{df(h(x))}{dh} = \dfrac{d a^{k} f(x)}{d(ax)} = \dfrac{a^k d  f(x)}{ad(x)} = \dfrac{a^{k-1} d f(x)}{dx}$

Comment: @SanjayGupta yes that is also correct. The $\nabla f$ at the end of my answer is $\nabla f(ax)$ which you show is equal to $a^{k-1} \nabla f(x)$. If you multiply $\nabla f(ax) = a^{k-1} \nabla f(x)$ with $a$, you have the statement you wanted to prove in $\mathbb{R}$.